# Spring Cloud Data Flow UI - runtime tab never loads

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have tried a few basic tutorials to create and deploy stream applications in spring cloud data flow. Every time I try to deploy the applications spring cloud data flow just hangs.  Even prior to deploying it seems that the runtime tab is not loading.  Is this a memory or version issue?  My docker version is Version 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hanging" behavior is typically observed when the Docker daemon running in your machine is under-provisioned.

Depending on the SCDF version in use, the Docker Compose experience includes SCDF (boot app), Skipper (boot app), MySQL, Kafka, Prometheus/Influx, and Grafana. Apart from SCDF and Skipper, all the other components require a lot of CPU/Memory.

We recommend a minimum of 8G RAM and 6 CPU cores. See below the screenshot of my local setup. You can compare this with yours and adjust accordingly. Perhaps then please tear everything down and retry.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what's going on at the server side (by looking at the logs) when this tab is clicked? The runtime operation involves retrieving all the currently running streaming applications. There could be issues checking the state of those applications.

Comment: how do you check logs for this, this is the first time I have used Spring Cloud Dataflow. Do they get output somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried Sabby Anandan's answer and bumped up my ram and cores allocation, it definitely seemed to improve performance. I was able to start data flow much faster. In order to get my run time tab to load I also needed to change another setting with docker. Under settings on the Shared Drives tab I had to select my C drive to be shared. After this I was able to start up spring cloud data flow and run my stream applications without issue. My guess is Spring Cloud was trying to access my C drive but did not have access so it was just hanging. Thanks everyone.[image]